# Using init() in map()

Tags: swift, swift2

## TL;DR

Why doesn't this work?

```
"abcdefg".characters.map(String.init) // error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

## Details

One really cool thing I like in Swift is the ability to convert a collection of one thing to another by passing in an init method (assuming an `init()` for that type exists).

Here's an example converting a list of tuples to instances of `ClosedInterval`.

```
[(1,3), (3,4), (4,5)].map(ClosedInterval.init)
```

That example also takes advantage of the fact that we can pass a tuple of arguments as a single argument as long as the tuple matches the function's argument list.

Here another example, this time converting a list of numbers to string instances.

```
(1...100).map(String.init)
```

Unfortunately, the next example does not work. Here I am trying to split up a string into a list of single-character strings.

```
"abcdefg".characters.map(String.init) // error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

`map()` should be operating on a list of `Character` (and indeed I was able to verify in a playground that Swift infers the correct type of [Character] here being passed into `map`).

`String` definitely can be instantiated from a `Character`.

```
let a: Character = "a"
String(a) // this works
```

And interestingly, this works if the characters are each in their own array.

```
"abcdefg".characters.map { [$0] }.map(String.init)
```

Or the equivalent:

```
let cx2: [[Character]] = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"]]
cx2.map(String.init)
```

I know that I could do this:

```
"abcdefg".characters.map { String($0) }
```

But I am specifically trying to understand why `"abcdefg".characters.map(String.init)` does not work (IMO this syntax is also more readable and elegant)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simplified repro:

```
String.init as Character -> String
// error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

This is because `String` has two initializers that accept one `Character`:

```
init(_ c: Character)
init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: Character)
```

As far as I know, there is no way to disambiguate them when using the initializer as a value.

As for `(1...100).map(String.init)`, `String.init` is referred as `Int -> String`. Although there are two initializers that accept one `Int`:

```
init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: Int)
init<T : _SignedIntegerType>(_ v: T)
```

Generic type is *weaker* than explicit type. So the compiler choose `stringInterpolationSegment:` one in this case. You can confirm that by <kbd>command</kbd> + click on `.init`.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Is there a reference document (or even an article) that describes using `.init` in this way (e.g. in map/flatMap, etc)?

Comment: You can disambiguate the two initialisers; use `String.init(_:)` to refer to the first one.