# Is it possible to pass Int.init to a function in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to do something like this:

```
var x = ["10","20",30"]
var y = x.map(Int.init)
```

but I get this error

> ambiguous reference to member 'init()'

I know that I can just write

```
var y = x.map { Int($0) }
```

But I was wondering if there is another way.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more about your need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using init() in map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906791/using-init-in-map).

Comment: @MartinR nice find.  Interesting that the compiler can't disambiguate the initializer.  Sometimes you can get lucky and things like `[false, true].map(!)` work.

Comment: Why do you want another way?  `var y = x.map { Int($0) }` seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: What is it that you dislike? Is it the reference to `$0`?

Comment: I want to understand how I can reference a specific function in swift.  For example. If I could get swift to understand that I want to use the Int(text:String) function, then I could get my first example to compile. Is this not possible?

Comment: The problem (I think) is that there is an `init?(_ text: String, radix: Int = default)` with a *default argument value.* There was a question about assigning  `print` to a variable recently, which has the same problem.

Comment: @MartinR [Error when assigning function to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44336134/2415822).  I would hammer with the dupe you linked above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that there doesn't exist an `Int` initialiser that has *only* a `String` parameter.

There [only exists](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/1540747-init):

```
init?(_ text: String, radix: Int = default)
```

Although the `radix:` parameter has a default value, this is only "filled in" for you by the compiler at the call-site of the initialiser.

Default parameter values aren't partially applied when getting a reference to the function itself, nor does the compiler generate additional overloads for all possible combinations of default parameter values. Not only would the latter add significant bloat to your code, but both options would break default parameter values that depend on being inserted at the call-site (e.g `#file` & `#line`).

To make this work properly, function values themselves would have to support default parameter values, which brings with it quite a bit of complexity. Although it could well be something that a future version of the language supports.

One simple solution to get the behaviour you want is to just write an extension on `Int` which adds an `init(_:)` initialiser that then forwards onto `init(_:radix:)`:

```
extension Int {
    /// Creates a new integer value from the given base-10 integer string, returning nil
    /// if the string is in an invalid format.
    init?(_ string: String) {
        // we're saying (_:radix:) in order to disambiguate the call, the compiler
        // will insert the default parameter value of radix: for us.
        self.init(_:radix:)(string)
    }
}
```

Note in Swift 4, this could be an extension of [`FixedWidthInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger), which provides the implementation of `init(_:radix:)` for the standard library's integer types.

Now you can say:

```
let x = ["10", "20", "30"]
let y = x.map(Int.init) // [Optional(10), Optional(20), Optional(30)]
```

as `Int.init` now refers to our extension initialiser.

And this also works just as well with `flatMap(_:)`:

```
let y = x.flatMap(Int.init) // [10, 20, 30]
```

which will also filter out the `nil` elements from the transformation (the strings that weren't convertible to integers).

Comment: Nice! But `y` still returns `[Int?]`, maybe _optional_ Ints is not wanted. Then you can use this init in the extension in combination with `flatMap` instead of `map`

Comment: @Sajjon Yup, was just in the process of adding that when you commented :) It's not clear which of the two OP wants, but figured there was no harm in mentioning it.

Comment: nice! @b-roy-dawson you could also use this solution and put it in an extension to [String]. Like this: `extension Array where Element == String {
    var integers: [Int] {
        return flatMap(Int.init)
    }
}` with *usage:* `var y = x.integers`

Comment: @Sajjon I wouldn't use such an extension unless it was fileprivate, and used a lot in a file. It's too easy to just  write `flatMap(Int.init)`, so as to make it hard to justify such an extension

Comment: @Sajjon I agree with Alexander – also note that semantically, computed properties should be O(1), which yours isn't, you'd generally want to use a method instead for that (but again, you're really not saving much over just saying `flatMap(Int.init)`).

Comment: Just brainstorming some syntactical sugar for the OP... Whatever he wants to do is up to him :) but yes one should be restrictive with such extensions agreed :)

Comment: At the risk of revealing my ignorance: Where is the `init(_:radix:)` syntax defined? I have seen that only inside `#selector` so far.

Comment: @MartinR For initialisers, it's documented in the "[Initializer Expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/function-call-expression)" section of the grammar, specifically `initializer-expression → postfix-expression ­. ­init ­(­argument-names­)­`, where `argument-names` are a list of identifiers separated by `:` that correspond to the initialiser's argument labels (and then to call, you're looking at a `function-call-expression`).

Comment: @MartinR For arbitrary members, see the "[Explicit Member Expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/initializer-expression)" section – the disambiguation grammar for that mirrors the initialiser disambiguation (`explicit-member-expression → postfix-expression­ . ­identifier ­(argument-names­)­`).

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes down to inability to assign a function with a defaulted argument (such as `Int.init(_ text: String, radix: Int = default)`) to a place where it could only "fit" if the defaulted argument "didn't exist".

When you make your own closure, `{ Int($0) }`, you're telling the compiler you want the default value of the `radix` to apply. This this doesn't happen implicitly, unfortunately.