# Is it possible to get a first class function with default parameters?

Tags: swift, default-parameters, first-class-functions

I have a bunch of similar functions, which all have the same parameters. Some of the parameters have a default value.

Here are two of them:

```
func debug(_ message: String, eventid: String = Foundation.UUID().uuidString, logFile: String = "log.log", evenIdents: Bool = true) -> String

func warning(_ message: String, eventid: String = Foundation.UUID().uuidString, logFile: String = "log.log", evenIdents: Bool = true) -> String
```

I want now to save this functions in a switch into a variable and call it later, but I want also, that I can leave out some of the default parameters. I tried it like this:

```
let function: (String, String) -> String    

switch logStyle {
case .debug:
    function = debug(_:logFile:)
case .warning:
    function = warning(_:logFile:)
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and gives me the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'debug(_:logFile:)'`.

Is it possible with Swift somehow or not?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44828903/2976878. One possible solution is to use a closure expression in which the default arguments can be evaluated, e.g `function = { debug($0, logFile: $1) }`.